# Paypal button with Danish amount and currency

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am working on a Danish web site. I have created the buy now Button but having some problem with the amount.

The amount is 10,00 DKK not 10.00 DKK. 
10,00 and 10.00 has different meaning.

if I use

```
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00" />
```

it works.
but if I use

```
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10,00" />
```

it does not work. I get an error

```
"the link you have used to enter the paypal system contains an incorrectly formatted item amount."
```

Is there any solution to this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats the difference between 10,00 DKK and 10.00 DKK?

The `value` attribute is just a number where "." is used as decimal mark, nothing else. This attribute has no other meaning.